# Prevent user from overwriting the record CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a process that runs at specific time and updates records in "Open" state and disables them.
Recently I had a case when user opened the record almost at the same minute as the process was doing it's job. So while user was manually entering the data, process would already update the record and set record status to "Disabled". However, since user doesn't refresh the screen, when record saved, the status would change back to "Open" and wipe some data.

Any ideas on how this overwriting can be prevented?

P.S Process and the user should both have power to edit the record, but once it's disabled it should be locked somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In crm 2011, not sure if the optimistic concurrency is available in any update rollups. But Optimistic concurrency using row version concept was introduced later in 2015 update 1.

You can implement similar approach, by querying the record again and verify the modifiedon between DB record & user modified record, then stop the execution & ask user to refresh to get latest data.